# Using jQuery to build connecting lines between animated objects

Tags: jquery, line, jquery-animate, draw

I'm building an animated navigation based on the idea of a molecular diagram. It currently contains 3 hexagons that are animated when any one of them is hovered over.

Here is what I have so far: http://www.billjordandesign.com/tutorials/hexagon_test.html

I'd like to include lines that connect the hexagons (like a diagram) that move along with the hexagons as they are animated so they appear to stay connected.

Does anyone have any advice on where to start looking for a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I think jQuery might not be the best bet, unless you're sticking with perfectly straight lines all the time.

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be a better fit.

If you're stuck w/ jQuery, you may want to check out some of [these plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/graph).

Comment: Using Raphael will enable you to draw those hexagons in SVG (VML in IE) so you won't have any of that not-so-pretty pixellation. Also, that way you'll be able to define the vertices of your hexagons more precisely and drawing and animating lines between 2 defined points in SVG will be achieved with relative ease.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  It looks like I will be able to find the answer via one of your links.

Comment: Raphael isn't free, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You May also want to check out a framework called easeljs. Its not quite as robust as raepheal, but that may be an advantage. [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/)